# Imprimir el número de palabras con n caracteres en python

Tags: python, lista

Ando algo perdido y solo he podido sacar el numero de palabras en el contador, pero no sé como imprimirlo.

```py
mi_cadena = "El veloz muerciélago hidú, comía feliz cardillo y kiwi. La cigüeña tocada el saxofon derás del palenque de paja."
lista_palabras= mi_cadena.split()
n_max = 0

palabra in lista_palabras:
    if len(palabra) > n_max:
        n_max = len(palabra) 
        
print(n_max)

contador = [0 for n in range (n_max+1)]

for palabra in lista_palabras:
    n_car = len(palabra)
    contador [n_car] +=1
```

El resultado debería darme algo parecido a esto:

```
 "1 palabra de 1 carácter"
 "4 palabras de 2 carácteres"
 "1 palabra de 3 carácteres"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supongo que estas usando python, puedes definir una lista de resultado donde el indice es el largo de la palabra porque este no cambia y el valor su cantidad porque este si varia. Para evitar el error índice fuera de lista puedes usar un while dentro del for que asegure que siempre existirá la posición.

```
mi_cadena = "El veloz muerciélago hidú, comía feliz cardillo y kiwi. La cigüeña tocada el saxofon derás del palenque de paja."
lista_palabras= mi_cadena.split(" ")
resultado = []

for palabra in lista_palabras: 
    largo = len(palabra)
    while len(resultado) < largo+1:
        resultado.append(0)
    resultado[largo] = resultado[largo] +1

for x in range(0,len(resultado)):
    print(str(resultado[x]) + " palabras de " + str(x) + " caracteres")
```

El resultado sera

```
0 palabras de 0 caracteres
1 palabras de 1 caracteres
4 palabras de 2 caracteres
1 palabras de 3 caracteres
0 palabras de 4 caracteres
7 palabras de 5 caracteres
1 palabras de 6 caracteres
2 palabras de 7 caracteres
2 palabras de 8 caracteres
0 palabras de 9 caracteres
0 palabras de 10 caracteres
1 palabras de 11 caracteres
```

Si quieres evitar los 0 palabras solo agrega un if resultado[x] != 0 antes del print

Answer (score 0):

Una solución Pythonica:

```
largos = [len(x) for x in mi_cadena.split()]
for largo in set(largos):
    print(f"{largos.count(largo)} palabras de largo {largo}")
```

Primero creamos la lista `largos` con los largos de cada palabra en la frase.

```
largos = [len(x) for x in mi_cadena.split()]
```

Con `set(largos)` obtenemos los largos sin repetición. Puedo iterar sobre estos y por cada largo distinto, contar cuantas veces aparece en `largos`.

#### Demo

```
mi_cadena = "El veloz muerciélago hidú, comía feliz cardillo y kiwi. La cigüeña tocada el saxofon derás del palenque de paja."
largos = [len(x) for x in mi_cadena.split()]
for largo in set(largos):
    print(f"{largos.count(largo)} palabras de largo {largo}")
```

produce:

```
1 palabras de largo 1
4 palabras de largo 2
1 palabras de largo 3
7 palabras de largo 5
1 palabras de largo 6
2 palabras de largo 7
2 palabras de largo 8
1 palabras de largo 11

Process finished with exit code 0
```